# Rotate iPad Video out when connected to a monitor

Tags: ipad, hdmi

I have a HDMI -> iPad adapter that I'm using to connect my iPad to a monitor to do a demo at a tradeshow. The monitor I'm using is placed vertically, so I need to rotate the video out from the iPad to match it. I couldn't find any way to do this in the settings app.

Does anyone know a way? (Cydia apps are fine too)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's currently no way to do this system-wide.  If you make the app you're using for the demo, you should consider making the app do the rotation for you.

Design the app so when it's in landscape mode it displays a portrait mode screen (ie, the app always appears rotated on its side).  Then hold the ipad in landscape mode, turn rotation lock on so it stays that way, start your app, then use your app with the correct orientation.  Turn your monitor on its side to see the faked portrait mode.

You can also do this for presentations if you turn all your slides on the side.

However there's currently no way to do this for apps not designed for it.

Answer (score 0):

When I connect my iPad to an HDMI connector, the video orientation changes as I move the iPad around. So if you need Portrait mode, then hold the iPad in portrait mode.

Comment: Hmm, the rotation happens the wrong way too. Imagine you have your physical monitor placed on its side instead of its base. Even if you turn your iPad, the output is still oriented to look right if you have your monitor on its base..

Comment: I'm not following. The monitor that we use supports different orientations. If I put the monitor vertically (Portrait), then the iPad display fills the entire screen when I hold it in Portrait. if I hold the iPad in Landscape, then I get a letterbox effect on the monitor. If I put the monitor in Landscape, then I get a similar effect.

Comment: For whatever it is worth, it works the same on our higher end projectors as well. However, I have noticed that the video behavior is different from iPad2 and iPad. I am using an iPad2, so this may not be relevant.

Comment: Hmm, (2) is what's not happening for me. There seems to be no way to set the monitor up in Portait mode. I mean, I can tilt it physically, but the video is still wrong. I guess it's a monitor setting I should be looking for then. Let me get back to you.

Comment: Just using the monitor in the landscape mode for now. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You should use a monitor with rotation capabilities! 
Ipad sends vertical image and monitors fit that image so that all parts of the image are show, that causes black sides with a centered image on a normal horizontal screen. 
Just get a monitor that rotates incoming signals. It will be full screen on monitor full portrait on ipad.. voila!